# Does static initialization throw a system_error?

Tags: c++, c++11

Since C++11 static variables are initialized thread-safe. That's usually done with double-checked locking (DCL). DCL needs a mutex to synchronize the initialization if the initialization hasn't been done yet. Even if DCL wouldn't be used you'd need a mutex to synchronize the intialization. So does the standard say somewhere that static variables may throw a system_error on their first usage before the constructor is actually called ?

If you try this code ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<unsigned Thread>
struct SleepAtInitialize
{
    SleepAtInitialize()
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for( 1s );
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto unroll = []<size_t ... Indices>( index_sequence<Indices ...>, auto fn )
    {
        ((fn.template operator ()<Indices>()), ...);
    };
    constexpr unsigned N_THREADS = 10;
    vector<jthread> threads;
    threads.reserve( N_THREADS );
    unroll( make_index_sequence<N_THREADS>(),
        [&]<unsigned Thread>()
        {
            threads.emplace_back(
                [&]<unsigned IObj>( integral_constant<unsigned, IObj> )
                {
                    static SleepAtInitialize<IObj> guard;
                }, integral_constant<unsigned, Thread>() );
        } );
}
```

... you notice that there's not a central mutex for all initialitation.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255225/discussion-on-question-by-edison-von-myosotis-does-static-initialization-throw-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

> So does the standard say somewhere that static variables may throw a system_error

No, although in order to validate this assertion, one needs to read the entirety of the standard and check what every sentence says.

What the standard (or at least a recent draft) does say is as follows:

> [[stmt.dcl](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#3)] ... If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization

This precludes any possibility of throwing an exception before completion of the initialization.